# Cannot save printed document on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Since recently, I can no longer save the documents my app prints as pdf file from chrome.

I successfully print the document to the browser (actual content replaced with dummy text), and when I hit save, the popup just gets stuck at this "Saving..." state, and I need to hit Esc to cancel the printing popup and bring browser back to life. This is only happening on Chrome, everything works perfectly on Firefox. I'm using version Version 117.0. on MacOS 12.2 Monterey.

[image]

Any idea why this happens.